# How does Corona SDK work ? Is Lua converted to Objective C?

Tags: iphone, lua

Corona SDK says you code in LUA. But afterwards does it translate to Objective C ? Can I see source code generated somewhere ?

If it uses an engine to interpret Lua is this authorized by Apple Store ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corona SDK is a closed source game engine and App development kit. You only get access to the Lua code and interface.

What kind of engine they're running behind the scenes and which language it uses is speculative for the most part. I think I remember that on their forum or blog it was mentioned that it's powered by a C++ engine that they wrote. Makes sense if you consider that Corona Apps run on both iOS and Android devices, the latter doesn't support development with Objective-C.

Comment: If it uses an engine to interpret Lua is this authorized by Apple Store ?

Comment: Apple has revised the ban on interpreted code.  The latest version only forbids remote loading of code.  Of course this may change so YMMV